# Convert NumPy array to string when copying key from dictionary

Tags: python, string, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

I have a key from a dictionary which is:

```
key = "-1-1-1100011-->-10-1-100011"

print(key)

-1-1-1100011-->-10-1-100011
```

I've copied the key as:

```
previous key = np.copy(key)

print(previous key)

-1-1-1100011-->-10-1-100011
```

However this changes the type of variable from a `str` to a `numpy.ndarray`. Is there any way around this so when I copy the key as a new variable it stays as a string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to copy the string? In Python, copying an immutable object virtually never makes sense.

Comment: `np.copy` says it `Return an array copy of the given object.`.  It is just `np.array` with the `copy=True` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't copy the key.

Strings are immutable, so you can just assign `key` to `previous_key` like so:

```
previous_key = key
```

Changing the value assigned to `key` won't change the value of `previous_key`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use numpy to do so, this code may help:

```
np.copy(key).tostring().decode('utf-8')
```

But why do you want to "copy" a string?

Comment: Except you should never need to do this. A string is immutable - there is no need to copy it, ever.